# input type="date" not show value in chrome > 30

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, date

from my SQL Server i become a value of "03.11.2014". This value i want show in a input type of date like:

```html
<input type="date" value={{myDate}}>
```

In the Internet Explorer this will show right, but without a date picker. Show like a textbox.

In Google Chrome i don´t became any value.
I have googled, but it looks like that Chrome expected the date in "2014-11-03".

What´s the right workarround to show a datetime picker with the right value in BOTH browsers?

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to put quotes around "{{myDate}}" so {{myDate}} can be passed appropriately to the value attribute.

You'll want to create your own filter that will parse that string from being mm.dd.yyyy to yyyy-dd-mm. Depending on your datepicker, you then might need to then re-convert the string you just created to become a date again. If so, just add a line in the filter that does so.

Here's an example to start from for the filter:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .filter('reformatDate', function() {
    return function(input) {
      input = input.splice('.');
      return input[2] + "-" + input[1] + "-" + input[0];
    };
  })
```

which you then call (after injecting the 'myApp' dependency in the controller):

```
value="{{myDate | reformatDate}}"
```